# Why is window.location showing csp error and how can it be handle if u are using node as backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

If the data is send to backend directly from the html it work but if send from JavaScript the console response success but the browser show error... Csp error

I try sign-in it returns success and I expect to see my dashboard but instead csp error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.